# Duplicated call in node Readable stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, node-streams

### The problem

So, I have [this code](https://github.com/DanielSLucas/SmBusiness/blob/master/cash-book/src/modules/movements/usecases/export-movements.service.ts), a Readable stream that reads the movements from de DB page by page, but I was getting duplicated records for some reason.

```js
      const readMovements = new Readable({
        async read() {
          while (true) {
            const movements = await getMovements(page, perPage);

            if (movements.length) {
              const data = JSON.stringify(movements);

              page++;
              this.push(data);
            } else {
              break;
            }
          }

          this.push(null);
        },
      });
```

### My solution

Then I [changed this](https://github.com/DanielSLucas/SmBusiness/commit/5f27a1152ae03f4e0eb6fab3da229d66e84542ad). The Readable became an async generetor below, and there was no more duplicated records

```js
      async function* readMovements() {
        while (true) {
          const movements = await getMovements(page, perPage);

          if (!movements.length) break;

          const data = JSON.stringify(movements);

          page++;
          yield data;
        }
      }
```

### My question

Do anyone knows why this was happening?

*I would like to keep using a Readable stream, because the async generator code runs slower than the first version. So if you have a way to make it work, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the `read()` method is called every time the resource is ready to read some more data. So, what you're doing is running that while loop every time `read()` is called (hence the duplicate calls).

Fix this by creating an internal property called something like `#registered` and using it to ensure the loop only runs once.

```
import { Readable } from 'stream';

export class YourStream extends Readable {
    #registered = false;

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    _read(): void {
        if (this.#registered) return;
        this.#registered = true;

        // do your stuff here
    }
}
```